# NodeJS app running in Plesk "npm install", "touch tmp/restart.txt" at webhook not working

Tags: node.js, webhooks, plesk

My problem is that I enabled "Enable additional deploy actions" at Plesk and i set this 2 command:

```
npm install
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

My problem is that it's not working in this way. However when I only keep the `touch tmp/restart.txt` and remove the `npm install` then the touch is working and the restart is successful. But I would like to have that npm install command, what is the right way to use it? I even tried `npm install && touch tmp/restart.txt` but nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your Domain Plesk account. **Hosting & DNS** > **Web Hosting Access**

Change **Access to the server over SSH** to /bin/bash then Apply.

It works on me.